# updating included files in a Basic MSI project from command line in Installshield 2012

Tags: installshield

I have a Basic MSI project in installshield 2012 and currently every time I want to build a release I have to manually go and update the included file, if needed. What I want to do is to include this process in our build process so that I can update the Basic MSI project from command line though a script and than create a installer.

The problem that I have is that I cannot find a way to update the project file from command line. I do not know if there is any other way to achieve my goal, maybe there is another type of project in installshield that can do this.

Can anyone help me regarding this problem?

cheers,

es

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "manually go and update the included file"?

Comment: first thing, you don't need to update files each time while making a new build. You just need to copy latest files to relative path from where InstallShiled picking those while build process.  
Second thing, you can update project files or any files as well from your script. You also need to create InstallShield project object in your script.

Comment: That is the question, where is the Basic MSI script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ISCmdBld.exe from installshield to build from command line
http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/ISCmdBldParam.htm#Ref-Command-LineTools_3873826509_1033924